# Apply functions to hourly data in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data in HISTORY table with column names as:

```
ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, VALUE

51,2015-04-17 01:00:00,2015-04-17 01:10:00,98
51,2015-04-17 01:10:00,2015-04-17 01:20:00,96
51,2015-04-17 01:20:00,2015-04-17 01:30:00,97
51,2015-04-17 01:30:00,2015-04-17 01:40:00,99
51,2015-04-17 01:40:00,2015-04-17 01:50:00,98
51,2015-04-17 01:50:00,2015-04-17 02:00:00,105
51,2015-04-17 02:00:00,2015-04-17 02:10:00,103
51,2015-04-17 02:10:00,2015-04-17 02:20:00,101
51,2015-04-17 02:20:00,2015-04-17 02:30:00,100
51,2015-04-17 02:30:00,2015-04-17 02:40:00,104
51,2015-04-17 02:40:00,2015-04-17 02:50:00,102
51,2015-04-17 02:50:00,2015-04-17 03:00:00,98
51,2015-04-17 03:00:00,2015-04-17 03:10:00,97
51,2015-04-17 03:10:00,2015-04-17 03:20:00,96
51,2015-04-17 03:20:00,2015-04-17 03:30:00,99
51,2015-04-17 03:30:00,2015-04-17 03:40:00,100
51,2015-04-17 03:40:00,2015-04-17 03:50:00,101
51,2015-04-17 03:50:00,2015-04-17 04:00:00,102
51,2015-04-17 04:00:00,2015-04-17 04:10:00,99
51,2015-04-17 04:10:00,2015-04-17 04:20:00,104
51,2015-04-17 04:20:00,2015-04-17 04:30:00,105
51,2015-04-17 04:30:00,2015-04-17 04:40:00,103
51,2015-04-17 04:40:00,2015-04-17 04:50:00,98
51,2015-04-17 04:50:00,2015-04-17 05:00:00,97
51,2015-04-17 05:00:00,2015-04-17 05:10:00,101
51,2015-04-17 05:10:00,2015-04-17 05:20:00,103
51,2015-04-17 05:20:00,2015-04-17 05:30:00,101
51,2015-04-17 05:30:00,2015-04-17 05:40:00,105
51,2015-04-17 05:40:00,2015-04-17 05:50:00,102
51,2015-04-17 05:50:00,2015-04-17 06:00:00,98
```

I want to apply the function like max() to the VALUE column but with some frequency. If frequency is suppose 1hour then max function will be applied for 5 different sets for this data.

Ex. From start time 2015-04-17 01:00:00 to 2015-04-17 02:00:00 and so on.
How to achieve this in r. Final output would be like this:

```
51, 2015-04-17 02:00:00, 105
51, 2015-04-17 03:00:00, 102
51, 2015-04-17 04:00:00, 104
51, 2015-04-17 05:00:00, 105
51, 2015-04-17 06:00:00, 105
```

where above columns are ID, START_TIME upto which max() is calculated, value which is the result of max() function for that hour.
How to make this possible in r. Using intervals or something else?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(MAX_VALUE = max(VALUE)), 
             by = .(ID, START_TIME = as.POSIXct(START_TIME, format = "%F %H") + 3600)]
#    ID          START_TIME MAX_VALUE
# 1: 51 2015-04-17 02:00:00       105
# 2: 51 2015-04-17 03:00:00       104
# 3: 51 2015-04-17 04:00:00       102
# 4: 51 2015-04-17 05:00:00       105
# 5: 51 2015-04-17 06:00:00       105
```

Or a similar solution without any packages dependencies

```
df$START_TIME2 <-  as.POSIXct(df$START_TIME, format = "%F %H") + 3600
aggregate(VALUE ~ ID + START_TIME2, df, max)
#   ID         START_TIME2 VALUE
# 1 51 2015-04-17 02:00:00   105
# 2 51 2015-04-17 03:00:00   104
# 3 51 2015-04-17 04:00:00   102
# 4 51 2015-04-17 05:00:00   105
# 5 51 2015-04-17 06:00:00   105
```

Comment: Working but what if the frequency is changed from 1 hour to 2 hour? If I replaced the 3600 in above answer with 7200 then it wont work properly.

Comment: I actually don't understand your desired output. Why do you want to add one extra hour? Why just `as.POSIXct(df$START_TIME, format = "%F %H")` isn't good enough?

Comment: Because frequency will be decided at runtime such that max function should applied for 1hour values or 2hour values. So.

Comment: I meant- why are you adding an extra hour. Anyhow, for you second question, if you want to run it for every two hours, try `setDT(df)[, .(MAX_VALUE = max(VALUE)), by = .(ID, START_TIME = (as.POSIXlt(START_TIME)$hour + 1) %/% 2)]`

Comment: More closer to the answer but it does not getting START_TIME in the required format. Should I use POSIXct instead of POSIXlt?

Comment: You want this aggregated by `ID` too?

Comment: Yes. I will try to explain more. If the frequency is 1hour then max will be calculated from 01:00:00 to 02::00:00, 02:00:00 to 03:00:00 and so on. If the frequency is 2 hour then max will be calculated from 01:00:00 to 03:00:00, 03:00:00 to 05:00:00 and so on. Ok? Also please help me to improve the question to make it more readable ans more understandable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75709/discussion-between-pratik-patil-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
HISTORY %>% 
  group_by(ID, TIME = format(START_TIME + 60*60, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")) %>% 
  summarise(MAX_VALUE = max(VALUE))
#   ID                TIME MAX_VALUE
# 1 51 2015-04-17 02:00:00       105
# 2 51 2015-04-17 03:00:00       104
# 3 51 2015-04-17 04:00:00       102
# 4 51 2015-04-17 05:00:00       105
# 5 51 2015-04-17 06:00:00       105
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, max(VALUE), by = .(START_TIME = sub(":.*", "", START_TIME))]
     START_TIME  V1
1: 2015-04-17 01 105
2: 2015-04-17 02 104
3: 2015-04-17 03 102
4: 2015-04-17 04 105
5: 2015-04-17 05 105
```

Comment: I've edited your solution so it will be a one liner, but you are still not meeting the exact desired output.